# How to boot a Windows on another solid state drive alongside Ubuntu on another solid state drive?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have two SSDs. On one of them, Ubuntu, and on one of them Windows. I installed Windows first and Ubuntu second. Now even if I manually boot into my Windows SSD, I get taken to Ubuntu. What's more puzzling is that my mobo now won't let me choose either of the SSDs as the default boot, only lettig me to choose an unknown drive. It still does boot into Ubuntu nonetheless.

Now what I wanna do is to use Grub to boot these two alongside each other. How can I achieve that? In case you're wondering, the Windows drive is healthy as I can see it in Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  With multiple drives you do not run auto fix but only advanced mode after someone has reviewed your configuration. Are both installs UEFI?

Comment: @oldfred here it is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dpsbKgVQy2/

Comment: And to be honest I'm not sure if both of them are UEFIs.

Comment: It says you have UEFI hardware, but installed Windows in the old BIOS/MBR configuration. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI mode since Windows 8 released in 2012, but users can install in UEFI or BIOS. DO NOT use auto fix. You want Windows boot loader on sda & grub only on sdb. You can use Boot-Repair's advanced options, but better to use Windows repair/recovery flash drive for Windows repairs. It looks like Ubuntu is UEFI, but Ubiquity installer will not install grub correctly unless first drive has ESP. And UEFI should be gpt. Better to reinstall Windows in UEFI?